# Same XPath Node returns different result

Tags: xpath

Imagine I got the following simple `.xml` file

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <n id = "1"/>    
    </c>  
    <n id = "2"/>    
    <n id = "3"/>    
  </b>
</a>
```

and the following to queries and their respective result:

```
"//n[preceding::n]/@id" result = 2 3
"//n[preceding::n and following-sibling::n]/@id" result = 2
```

To me, both queries "stop" at the same node, which is  `<n id = "2"/>` , because it is the first node called `n`, which has a `preceding::n` (a preceding node called an) and is also the first node called `n`, with a `preceding::n` (a preceding node called n) a `following-sibling::n` (a following sibling called n)

So why do I get different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preceding::n` refers to [any node in the structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding)

> preceding
> Indicates all the nodes that precede the context node in the document except any ancestor, attribute and namespace nodes.

This one would get same results

```
xmllint --xpath '//n[preceding-sibling::n or following-sibling::n]/@id' test.xml
 id="2" id="3"
```

Comment: you mean refers to "all" nodes in the structure?

Comment: Yes, that's what the documentation says as I understand.